# Android - Cance/Stop/Kill AsyncTask Forcefully without loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Anyone know if it possible to kill/stop AsyncTask without loop.
There was many examples with loop but the task which I should do in **doInBackground()** function only one function which in some cases take long time and I shall stop it for example in **onPause**. If it possible or I should use another task for example Futuretask.

Thanks in advance.

The code like this:

```
class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, " ---- ProcessTask -- doInBackground ----");
        // Task
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(TAG, " ---- ProcessTask -- onPostExecute ----");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Boolean result) {
        super.onCancelled(result);
        Log.i(TAG, " ---- ProcessTask -- onCancelled ----");
    }
}

... 
ProcessTask myTask;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    myTask = new OCRProcessTask();
    myTask.cancel(false);
    myTask.execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    myTask.cancel(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the `AsyntTask` by setting `cancel(true)` to the task.

```
new MyAsyncTask().cancel(false);
```

Comment: I add code. You mean such ?
If I try lick that **doInBackground** function not called.
If something I understand not right?

Comment: You can't cancel and execute in the same time, I guess. What you can do is, by checking the Async Status and cancel it if it's still running or something.

Comment: That mean that I should have loop on "doInBackground" function, yes??? And I can not stop it without loop ?